# Is it possible to test the following without spyon ? JEST ENZYME

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Here is the code that Im trying to test using Jest and Enzyme.
Im wondering if is possible to test if its working properly without using spyON

```
toggleIsChecked = (e) => {
if (this.state.key && this.state.value && this.state.isChecked === false){
  let localState = {}
  localState['isChecked'] = true
  let keyValuePairObj = Object.assign({}, this.state, localState)
  keyValuePairObj['type'] = this.props.type
  keyValuePairObj['id'] = this.props.id
  if (this.props.subType) {
    keyValuePairObj['subType'] = this.props.subType
  }
  this.props.addNewKeyValue(keyValuePairObj)
  this.setState({
    isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
  })
} else {
  this.setState({
    isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
  })
}
```

I ran online into an example and the answer that i received is the following:

```
it("should call sort ids", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<KeyValuePair />);
  wrapper.instance().toggleIsChecked = jest.fn();
  wrapper.update();    // Force re-rendering 
  wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
  expect(wrapper.instance().toggleIsChecked).toBeCalled();
});
```

It is failing at the moment and I know the answer above is not correct. How could I improve from the previous answer and test the code above to pass it

Thank you